# Filtering out rows that have a string field contained in one of the rows of another column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With two Pandas datasets

```
csv1 = pandas.read_csv('test1')
csv2 = pandas.read_csv('test2')
```

how to display all rows of `csv1` that have a `str1` field that is not a substring of any of the rows of `csv2`'s `str2` field?

Note: I tried with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) but it seems that its parameter `pat` should be a string and not a column of strings.

---

Example:

```
#csv1
id str1
1  abc
2  def
3  ghi
4  xyz

#csv2
data1 str2
69236 pghiww
9623  habcrv
6152  de
```

Then the output should be:

```
id str1
2  def
4  xyz
```

Indeed rows 2 and 4's `str1` fields are not contained in any of the row of `csv2`'s `str2`.

Comment: Doing the other way is much easier `df2[~df2.str2.str.contains("|".join(df1.str1))]`. It's an interesting question!

Comment: @Basj, let me know if there's any clarification you need with regards to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge with this problem is to not only detect whether there exists a match, but to figure out what matches what, and filter accordingly. One option using `str.contains` in a comprehension:

```
csv1 = csv1.iloc[[~csv2.str2.str.contains(x).any() for x in csv1.str1]]
print(csv1)
   id str1
1   2  def
3   4  xyz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @COLDSPEED! Just a few things, why the `.str.` and `any()`? Also, why `iloc` and not `loc`?

Comment: Also, it's possible to display *only those who match* (just remove the `~` in your code and it's done!). Then how could we add a column with the match? Ex:  `id str1 match` / `1 abc habcrv` / `3 ghi pghiww`.