# How to match rows when one row contain string from another row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, contains

My aim is to find `City` that matches row from column `general_text`, but the match must be exact.

I was trying to use searching `IN` but it doesn't give me expected results, so I've tried to use `str.contain` but the way I try to do it shows me an error. Any hints on how to do it properly or efficient?

I have tried code based on [Filtering out rows that have a string field contained in one of the rows of another column of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858780/filtering-out-rows-that-have-a-string-field-contained-in-one-of-the-rows-of-anot)

```
df['matched'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.City in x.general_text, axis=1)
```

but it gives me the result below:

```
data = [['palm springs john smith':'spring'],
    ['palm springs john smith':'palm springs'],
    ['palm springs john smith':'smith'],
    ['hamptons amagansett':'amagansett'],
    ['hamptons amagansett':'hampton'],
    ['hamptons amagansett':'gans'],
    ['edward riverwoods lake':'wood'],
    ['edward riverwoods lake':'riverwoods']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ 'general_text':'City'])

df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['general_text'].str.contain(
                                          x.['City']), axis = 1)
```

What I would like to receive by the code above is match only this:

```
data = [['palm springs john smith':'palm springs'],
    ['hamptons amagansett':'amagansett'],
    ['edward riverwoods lake':'riverwoods']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b\b` for exact match:

```
import re

f = lambda x: bool(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x['City']), x['general_text']))
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: bool(re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(x['City']), x['general_text']))

df['match'] = df.apply(f, axis = 1)
print (df)
              general_text          City  match
0  palm springs john smith        spring  False
1  palm springs john smith  palm springs   True
2  palm springs john smith         smith   True
3      hamptons amagansett    amagansett   True
4      hamptons amagansett       hampton  False
5      hamptons amagansett          gans  False
6   edward riverwoods lake          wood  False
7   edward riverwoods lake    riverwoods   True
```

Comment: Both  works perfectly fine and give the same result but what is the difference between `re.search` and `re.findall`?

Comment: @KWar -You can check [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-difference-between-research-and-refindall-what-is-the-meaning-of-reverbose) - here is working same, because if use bool with `None` for `re.search` get `False` and if use bool with empty lists `[]` for `re.findall` also get False