# Replacing values from two columns when they are similar

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns; **Name** and **BrandName**. The first column contains values like the name of the products, whereas the second one is the product's brand name. There are some occasions where they have similar names - for example, Coca Cola.

[image]

In the image above you can see exactly what I am talking about. I will leave a piece of code for testing purposes:

```
data = [['Coca Cola', 'Coca Cola'], ['Coca Cola cherry', 'Coca Cola'], ['Coca Cola life', 'Coca Cola'], ['Coca Cola Life', 'Coca Cola']]
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'BrandName'])
```

What I am trying to do is set every value from column **BrandName** to "Unknown" whenever the product's name contains the same words as the brand name. Take the image above, for example. I was only able to set the first row's Brand name to "Unknown" using the code below:

```
testdf["BrandName"] = np.where(testdf["Name"] == testdf["BrandName"], "Unknown", testdf["BrandName"])
```

However, I didn't figure out yet how to set the condition in a way so when **Name** contains the whole content of column **BrandName**, the latter's value becomes "Unknown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom lambda function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57950800/2901002) to `np.where`:

```
import re

f = lambda x: bool(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(x['BrandName']), x['Name']))

testdf['match'] = np.where(testdf.apply(f, axis = 1), "Unknown", testdf["BrandName"])
print (testdf)
               Name  BrandName    match
0         Coca Cola  Coca Cola  Unknown
1  Coca Cola cherry  Coca Cola  Unknown
2    Coca Cola life  Coca Cola  Unknown
3    Coca Cola Life  Coca Cola  Unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `mask` an `apply`:

```
testdf['BrandName'] = (testdf.BrandName.mask(testdf.apply(
                                             lambda x: x.BrandName in x.Name, axis=1), 
                                             'Unkown'))

           Name      BrandName
0         Coca Cola    Unkown
1  Coca Cola cherry    Unkown
2    Coca Cola life    Unkown
3    Coca Cola Life    Unkown
​
```